# Hacer un print dinámico de datos usando sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, curl, bottle

tengo una infraestructura de red integrada en Python Bottle y basada en nodos rpi que funcionan como puntos de acceso. La idea es mostrar en un servidor web todos los dispositivos conectados a cada nodo de forma independiente. Lo que tengo es un comando curl que envía tanto la dirección MAC como la calidad de la señal a través de JSON a una base de datos sqlite3. Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo se supone que puedo mostrar esos datos teniendo en cuenta que los dispositivos pueden cambiar de nodo o simplemente desconectarse?

He estado pensando en hacer, por ejemplo, 2 nodos en 2 tablas diferentes y luego hacer inserts y deletes, en función de si concecta o desconecta pero tal vez eso no sea muy eficiente.

EDIT:
He logrado hacer este código que permite insertar o reemplazar en BBDD la información recibida. Lo que dudo ahora es como poder eliminar una fila del dispositivo que se desconecte. La idea es ejecutar un curl cada 5 segundos para mandar data.json que actualice los datos constantemente en BBDD.

**bottle.py**

```
@route('/', method='POST')
def index():
    body = request.body.read().decode('utf8') # read directly HTTP input
    get_dict = json.loads(body) # decode json and get native python dict
    maclist = get_dict.get('maclist')
    signallist = get_dict.get('signallist')

    data_list = list(zip(maclist, signallist))
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    try:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO users (MAC,SIGNAL) VALUES(?,?)", data_list)
    except Exception as exc:
        c.executemany("REPLACE INTO users (MAC,SIGNAL) VALUES(?,?)", data_list)


    conn.commit()
    return "Items added."

@route('/data', method='GET')
def index():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db/users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
    return template('simple.tpl', rows = c.fetchall())
```

***data.json***

```
{
    "maclist": [
        "b6:a2:23:39:b5:27",
        "b1:a2:0b:37:4c:22"
    ],
    "signallist": [
        "-50",
        "-10"
    ]
}
```

***users.db***

```
MAC                SIGNAL
b6:a2:23:39:b5:27  -50       
b1:a2:0b:37:4c:22  -10
```

Si por ejemplo b6:a2:23:39:b5:27 se desconecta querría que se eliminara la fila completa.

Comment: La BD en SQLite3 la tienes sobre el nodo? o la envías a uno central?

Comment: no, la tengo en el lado del servidor

Comment: Con el mismo Bottle no? cuando envíes la información envías un identificador del nodo que estas recibiendo y haces un servicio donde el Bottle muestra la información, quieres el ejemplo de eso?

Comment: Claro, porque tambien necesito diferenciar el curl de ambos nodos

Comment: @DrakoRod Bottle funcionaría como el servidor y el conjunto de las rpi como clientes que envían información al servidor.

Comment: tiens un ejemplo de la información que envías? para ayudarte

Comment: O si no quieres poner la info y así mas o menos un ejemplo de como envías la info por curl.

Comment: @DrakoRod he editado mi pregunta échale un vistazo.

Comment: Mas o menos te entiendo pero porque no simplemente actualizas el registro? para que insertas?

Comment: @DrakoRod porque si es una nueva mac tengo que insertar, y si la señar mejora o empeora se actualiza solo la señal. Impide que se repitan las macs, pero claro si el dispositivo se desconecta del nodo1 y se conecta al nodo2 la idea es borrar la fila de una tabla y pasarla a otra